# xsl:key filter option to show data values in different rows

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I will be having xml as below:

```
<catalog>
    <performanceVO>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/1998">1998-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="10.73">10.73</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="4.35">4.35</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/1999">1999-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="97.91">97.91</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="86.54">86.54</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2000">2000-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="46.58">46.58</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="38.15">38.15</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2001">2001-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-20.48">-20.48</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-25.05">-25.05</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2002">2002-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-42.48">-42.48</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-45.79">-45.79</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2003">2003-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="43.55">43.55</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="35.28">35.28</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2004">2004-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="11.96">11.96</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="5.53">5.53</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2005">2005-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.55">5.55</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-0.51">-0.51</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2006">2006-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.03">5.03</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-1.02">-1.02</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2007">2007-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-1.60">-1.6</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-7.26">-7.26</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2008">2008-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-10.64">-10.64</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-15.78">-15.78</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2009">2009-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="11.83">11.83</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="5.41">5.41</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2010">2010-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="17.28">17.28</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="10.54">10.54</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2011">2011-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="8.35">8.35</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="2.12">2.12</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2012">2012-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="29.35">29.35</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="21.90">21.9</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2013">2013-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="68.64">68.64</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="58.95">58.95</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2014">2014-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="33.91">33.91</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="26.22">26.22</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2015">2015-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.50">5.5</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-0.57">-0.57</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2016">2016-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-17.16">-17.16</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-21.92">-21.92</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <bmCalYearDet>
               <benchMarkName>heading1</benchMarkName>
               <benchMarkOrder>1</benchMarkOrder>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2016</calYear>
                  <val alt="11.96">11.96</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2015</calYear>
                  <val alt="1.38">1.38</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2014</calYear>
                  <val alt="13.69">13.69</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2013</calYear>
                  <val alt="32.39">32.39</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2012</calYear>
                  <val alt="16.00">16</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2011</calYear>
                  <val alt="2.11">2.11</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2010</calYear>
                  <val alt="15.06">15.06</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2009</calYear>
                  <val alt="26.46">26.46</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2008</calYear>
                  <val alt="-37.00">-37</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2007</calYear>
                  <val alt="5.49">5.49</val>
               </bmCalDet>
            </bmCalYearDet>
            <bmCalYearDet>
            <benchMarkName>heading2</benchMarkName>
            <benchMarkOrder>2</benchMarkOrder>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2016</calYear>
                <val alt="-21.68">-21.68</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2015</calYear>
                <val alt="11.42">11.42</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2014</calYear>
                <val alt="34.32">34.32</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2013</calYear>
                <val alt="65.97">65.97</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2012</calYear>
                <val alt="32.29">32.29</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2011</calYear>
                <val alt="12.08">12.08</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2010</calYear>
                <val alt="15.25">15.25</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2009</calYear>
                <val alt="15.84">15.84</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2008</calYear>
                <val alt="-12.56">-12.56</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2007</calYear>
                <val alt="4.64">4.64</val>
            </bmCalDet>
        </bmCalYearDet>
    </performanceVO>
</catalog>
```

Below is my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="bmCalDet-by-year" match="bmCalDet" use="calYear" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:variable name="catalog" select="." />

    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="performanceVO/fAnReVal">
            <xsl:sort select="rtnDate" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() le 10">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:variable> 

    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(rtnDate, '-')" />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1st row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWOSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="rtnWOSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2nd row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="rtnWSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 3rd row here is the issue with the code-->
        <tr>
            <th>val</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $catalog)/val" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are two  tree node which differs with node . When I loop and use the code as  I'm getting two values in the same row. Tried filtering it with node  but couldn't able to filter. Can anyone please provide the pointers? issue is with third row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need an `xsl:for-each` on `bmCalYearDet` and then add a condition on the key to filter on the `benchMarkOrder`

```
<!-- 3rd row here is the issue with the code-->
<xsl:for-each select="performanceVO/bmCalYearDet">
    <xsl:variable name="benchMarkOrder" select="benchMarkOrder" />
    <tr>
        <th>val</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $catalog)[../benchMarkOrder = $benchMarkOrder]/val" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you could also write it like so

```
<!-- 3rd row here is the issue with the code-->
<xsl:for-each select="performanceVO/bmCalYearDet">
    <xsl:variable name="benchMarkOrder" select="." />
    <tr>
        <th>val</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $benchMarkOrder)/val" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your data. E.g. for year 2016 you have **two** `bmCalDet`
nodes. One with *val* = 11.96 and another with *val* = -21.68.

**Both** these nodes are returned when you call
`key('bmCalDet-by-year',...)` for year 2016.

So when you create row #3, you need **only the first** of these values.
Then change the instruction inside the loop to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'),
  $catalog)[1]/val" />
```

Note `[1]` added to get only the 1st node returned by `key`.

To get the second set of values (in row #4), repeat the whole fragment
creating row #3.
This time however, inside the `for-each` loop, you need **only the second** element from the
content returned by `key(...)`.
So instead of `[1]` (after `key(...)`) write `[2]`.

Comment: I want both the values but in different rows <tr>